# Android toolbar and menu issues

Tags: android, xml

when i set a menu into toolbar with  toolbar.inflateMenu() method , the menu item will place in a wrong position.

the right effect:

[image]

but when the application run in my cell phone, it become this:

[image]

here's the code:
menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_add"
    android:orderInCategory="80"
    android:title="@string/fitting_other"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="90"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

layout.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/theme_primary"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

java code:

```
 Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_ware_house);
}
```

that's all code, could anyone help me?

Comment: You should use `onCreateOptionsMenue` to inflate the menu and get the desired result. I am not sure of `toolbar.inflatemenu` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extend your activity with **AppcompactActivity** and use

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Remove this line

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_ware_house);
```

Use **onCreateOptionsMenu**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{        
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);

    return true;
}
```

Automatically the menu inflated will be shown in your toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Inflating the menu in your toolbar layout won't make it behave like an action bar menu. Do the following:

1. Ensure your Activity extends **AppCompatActivity**
2. Set the **Toolbar** instance as **ActionBar** by calling `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` in the `onCreate()` method
3. Inflate the menu in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method.

   Your complete code would be:

   ```
   public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       Toolbar toolbar;

       ...

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
           setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
           ...
       }

       ...

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           //Inflate menu_ware_house.xml as my menu
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_ware_house, menu);
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```

The layout and menu resource files are fine.
Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i think i found the problem. i write <item name="orientation ">vertical</item> in my base style. So.. but thank's anyway